# Complex ffmpeg multi-encode/streamcopy/muxing scenario: is this actually doable?

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, streaming, encoding

I'm trying to do multiple muxing/re-encode/copy operations on an input video with ffmpeg and have run into roadblocks with the methods I've tried; before I continue testing, I want to confirm whether this is actually even possible with the software. (This is for a live streaming setup that takes in one live stream from another PC on my LAN, and archives/restreams it to multiple RTMP targets, hence the `-re` flag and needing to do everything in one operation.)

The input video has one high-bitrate h.264 video stream and four PCM audio tracks.

The three outputs I need:

- one h.246 encode at 8Mbps, aac encode of audio track 1 only
- one h.264 encode at 12Mbps, aac encode of audio track 1 only (ideally
  using the same encode as the first output, i.e. only having to encode
  audio once)
- one pure streamcopy of the whole input to .mkv

(These commands may be full of errors and bad practices, just a general idea of the direction I'm going.)

I've tried using the `split`/`asplit` filters in combination with the `tee` muxer along these lines, which seems like it would work in theory except that using filters disallows streamcopy/codec passthrough (ironically no actual filtering is being done to the video stream in this case, other than passing it through).

```
ffmpeg -re -init_hw_device qsv=hw -filter_hw_device hw -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i $INPUT \
-filter_complex "[0:v]split=3[twitch][youtube][passv];[0:a]asplit[stream][passa]" \
-map:v "[twitch]" -map:v "[youtube]" -map:v "[passv]" -map:a "[stream]:0" -map:a "[passa]" \
-c:v:0 h264_qsv -profile:v:0 high -preset:v:0 medium -g 120 -b:v:0 8M -maxrate:v:0 8M -bufsize:v:0 4M \
-c:v:1 h264_qsv -profile:v:1 high -preset:v:0 medium -g 120 -b:v:1 12M -maxrate:v:1 12M -bufsize:v:1 6M \
-c:v:2 copy \
-c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 320k \
-c:a:1 copy \
-f tee "[select=\'v:0,a:0\']8mbps.mkv|[select=\'v:1,a:0\']12mbps.mkv|[select=\'v:2,a:1\']copy.mkv"
```

I also played around with simple stream mapping to multiple outputs, but it seems like it only actually processes one video and audio output each, and I'm not sure stream mapping can even be used this way so this one is likely a mess.

```
ffmpeg -re -init_hw_device qsv=hw -filter_hw_device hw -hwaccel qsv -hwaccel_output_format qsv -c:v h264_qsv -i $INPUT \
-map 0:0 -c h264_qsv -profile high -preset medium -g 120 -b 8M -maxrate 8M -bufsize 4M \
-map 0:0 -c h264_qsv -profile high -preset medium -g 120 -b 12M -maxrate 12M -bufsize 6M \
-map 0:1 -c aac -b 320k \
-map 0:a -c copy \
-f tee "[select=\'v:0,a:0\']8mbps.mkv|[select=\'v:1,a:1\']12mbps.mkv|[select=\'v:2,a:1\']copy.mkv"
```

To further complicate things, I'm using Quick Sync hardware encoding here and would want to apply `-vf hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,format=qsv` to each re-encode if possible, but in my initial testing it was unclear if two sets of filters is possible, even on different encodes.

At any rate, is this even achievable with ffmpeg, and how if so?

Comment: shortly: `ffmpeg -i in -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v h264 -c:a aac out1.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v h264 -c:a aac out2.mkv -map 0 -c copy out3.mkv`

Comment: [Here](https://superuser.com/a/1826947/635712) is an example for reusing the encoded aac audio using `tee` muxer. There is no need to use `-filter_complex`, `split` and `asplit`, stream mapping is sufficient (as commented). There is no need to use `hwupload=extra_hw_frames=64,format=qsv`. `-hwaccel qsv` applies using QSV hardware accelerated decoding, so there is no need to use `hwupload` (the frames are already uploaded).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use [tee demuxer](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/tee.htm.gz) for reusing the encoded aac audio, and use [stream mapping](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Map), and [stream specifiers](http://underpop.online.fr/f/ffmpeg/help/stream-specifiers.htm.gz):

`ffmpeg -y -c:v h264_qsv -i in.mkv -map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:a -c:v:0 h264_qsv -profile:v:0 high -preset:v:0 medium -g 120 -b:v:0 8M -minrate:v:0 8M -maxrate:v:0 8M -c:v:1 h264_qsv -profile:v:1 high -preset:v:1 medium -g 120 -b:v:1 12M -minrate:v:1 12M -maxrate:v:1 12M -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 320k -f tee "[select=\'v:0,a\']8mbps.mkv|[select=\'v:1,a\']12mbps.mkv" -map 0 -c copy copy.mkv`

Add `-re` and replace the input and output as needed.

---

- `-c:v h264_qsv` - applies QSV H.264 hardware accelerated decoding (we may aslo use `-hwaccel qsv`).
- `-map 0:v -map 0:v -map 0:a` - maps the input video stream to the "first" (`0`) and the "second" (`1`) output video streams (and map the audio stream).
- `-c:v:0 h264_qsv -profile:v:0 high -preset:v:0 medium -g 120 -b:v:0 8M -minrate:v:0 8M -maxrate:v:0 8M` - selectes `h264_qsv` video encoder, with all the parameters that applies output video stream `0`.
- `-c:v:1 h264_qsv -profile:v:1 high -preset:v:1 medium -g 120 -b:v:1 12M -minrate:v:1 12M -maxrate:v:1 12M` - selectes `h264_qsv` video encoder, with all the parameters that applies output video stream `1`.
- `-c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 320k` - selects the audio encoder and bitrate.
- `-f tee "[select=\'v:0,a\']8mbps.mkv|[select=\'v:1,a\']12mbps.mkv"` - "Muxing" the same encoded audio stream with the two different video streams.
  The first output video stream (`0`) is "Muxed" to `8mbps.mkv` output file.
  The second output video stream (`1`) is "Muxed" to `12mbps.mkv` output file.
- `-map 0 -c copy copy.mkv` - Applies a second output (because it comes after the first output).
  `-map 0` - Maps all the input streams from the input to the output.
  `-c copy` - Copy all the input streams without re-encoding.

---

For testing, I created a synthetic video file `in.mkv`:

`ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=size=1920x1080:rate=30 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -c:v libx264 -strict -2 -c:a dca -ar 44100 -pix_fmt yuv420p -t 5 in.mkv`

---

Notes:

- `-b:v:0 4M -minrate:v:0 4M -maxrate:v:0 4M` applies constant bitrate (I am not sure if you really need it).
- `bufsize` argument is not working with `h264_qsv` encoder (I didn't try to solve this).

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation, I actually got to roughly this same solution based on your original comment. The key was manually creating multiple output streams (e.g. the `c:v:1` syntax), which is a feature I wasn't aware of before. It's working perfectly now.